# remove the whole row with sed?

Tags: sed

I added a row to a document with a cat heredocument

```
cat <<-'DEFINE' >> ./wp-config.php
define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
DEFINE
```

I later wanted to remove it and did:

```
sed -i "s/define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );//g" ./wp-config.php
```

After removing it, I noticed an extra empty line where the code was - This is indeed the natural thing to happen - sed just deleted the code, not the whole row.

My question is, can I use sed to actually remove the whole row, and not just the code inside it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty line comes from you substituting the text with nothing.

Instead of using a substitution (`s`), use a deletion (`d`):

```
sed -i "/define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );/d" ./wp-config.php
```